# Run Oracle Procedure just to lock row, without returning a resultset

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to run a procedure to force a row lock on a row, but I don't want to return a result set to the client, nor do I actually want to update anything. Below is the proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_LOCK_Row
 (IDRow IN INTEGER)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM TBLTable
  WHERE IDRow = IDRow 
  FOR UPDATE;
END;
```

The problem is that I keep getting the error: `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`. Is there a way for me to lock the row without actually having to return a result set back to the client? The SQL Server equivalent is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_LOCK_Row(
  @IDRow INT)
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TBLTable WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE IDRow = @IDRow
```

Tks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how smart it is to code this way but this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_LOCK_Row
 (IDRow IN INTEGER)
IS
 dummy varchar2(1);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'x' into dummy
  FROM TBLTable
  WHERE IDRow = IDRow 
  FOR UPDATE;
END;
```

should do the trick.
Ronald - http://ronr.blogspot.com

Comment: Hi Pascal, I am glad to have been able to provide you with an answer that you accept.